# c++11 lambda function object member

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, c++14

I am writing a C++ library of abstract classes for some scientific computations. In one of the classes, I am using a function object so that I can pass it as an argument in a numerical algorithm. I have to do this as generally the calculation requires additional arguments that I can not pass in the numerical algorithm. I successfully implemented the code using a private class (nested class) for the construction of the function object. I am trying now to rewrite the class using lambdas for the creation of the function objects, but I am not sure how I can restrict access to specific member variables within lambdas.

I have below a simple program to illustrate the problem I am facing.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    A(int inI, int inJ) : _i(inI), _j(inJ)
    {
        create_functor();
    }

    A(const A& rtSide) : _i(rtSide._i),_j(rtSide._j)
    {
        create_functor();
    }

    A(A&& rtSide) : _i(rtSide._i), _j(rtSide._j)
    {
        rtSide.f = nullptr;
        create_functor();
    }

    A& operator=(A&& rtSide)
    {

        _i = rtSide._i;
        _j = rtSide._j;
        create_functor();

        rtSide.f = nullptr;

        return *this;
    }

    A& operator=(A& rtSide)
    {
        if (this == &rtSide)
            return *this;

        _i = rtSide._i;
        _j = rtSide._j;
        create_functor();

        rtSide.f = nullptr;

        return *this;
    }

    ~A() {}

    void reset_i(const int& newI) { _i = newI; }

    function<double(const double&)> f;

private:
    void create_functor()
    {
        f = [this](const double& inX) -> double {return inX * static_cast<double>(_i); };
    }

    int _i;
    int _j;
};

int main()
{

    A _A1(2,0);
    A _A2(1,0);

    _A2 = _A1;

    cout << _A2.f(2) << endl;

    _A2.reset_i(4);

    cout << _A2.f(2) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

While the above code works fine, I could not figure out how it would be possible to limit access to outer scope only for the member variable _i.

Any thoughts/suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: just out of curiosity: why do you want to do that (limit access)?

Comment: just out of curiosity as well... ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) you can use [`std::reference_wrapper<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) and capture that wrapper by value:

```
std::reference_wrapper<decltype(_i)> r = _i;
f = [r](const double& inX) -> double {return inX * static_cast<double>(r.get()); };
```

or its shorter equivalent:

```
auto r = std::ref(_i);
f = [r](const double& inX) -> double {return inX * static_cast<double>(r.get()); };
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f5401aea76db5775)

In [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) you can use a generalized lambda capture expression:

```
f = [&_i = _i](const double& inX) -> double {return inX * static_cast<double>(_i); };
```

[**DEMO 2**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9fa214b72dc2b30d)